# How can I intercept CTRL+V keypress and then alert what was pasted using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do the following:

- User presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> while focused on the
  webpage
- Page intercepts it and shows an alert with what the user has tried to
  paste

For example:

- User has "foo" in clipboard
- User presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> while focused on the
  webpage
- Page shows an alert with "foo" in it

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery, and I am not sure how can I implement this.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!